# UnhandledErrorDetected: Unspecified error COMException

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Struggling with an error that freezes the app and only occurs on the tablet (never on my laptop).  Seems to be related to quickly switching the hamburger menu.  I got one stack trace that incriminated a 3rd party control, but 9 of 10 times all I get is the following.  There are only a couple of "async void"s where I can't avoid them (overriding events) and from other logging, I believe the issue is in the XAML (methods are logging entry/exit):

> Unspecified error
>       : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error
>
> Unspecified error
>           at Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.UnhandledError.Propagate()
>           at Oceaneering.Commons.Utilities.Logger.CoreApplication_UnhandledErrorDetected(Object sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs e)

Setting up like this:

```
CoreApplication.UnhandledErrorDetected += CoreApplication_UnhandledErrorDetected;
```

And the receiving method is:

```
try {               
   e.UnhandledError.Propagate();
}
catch (Exception ex){
   logChannel.LogMessage(string.Format("Unhandled Exception: {0}:{1}", ex.Message, ex.ToString()));
   SaveToFileAsync().Wait();
}
```

Anything else I can do to gather more info?  Thanks!

Comment: Adding:  As I said before occasionally I do get a stack trace.  Just got one I haven't seen before, but seems that others have this one:

Unhandled Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component....

Comment: Any chance you could capture a dump file for the crash and share it out?

Comment: Thanks, but this was from a year ago.  Some Nuget updates cleared up the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the author confirms in a comment below the question itself, the error can be resolved with a NuGet update.

Check dependencies and version history at:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.InteropServices/